# About constant product

Tags: products, constants

If we had two number variables A and B with their product to be a constant C;
A x B = C.
Doesn't that mean that if I increased A by an amount "n" and decreased B with the same amount "n" , then their product should not change and stays equal to C.

But its not true, since for example : 5x3=15 ; (5-1)x(3+1)=16 and not equal to 15

I know that I have proved it wrong, but intuitively I'm still not convinced..

Comment: if you increase by multiplying, not adding. However if $a+b=c$ then $(a-n)+(b+n)$ is still $c$. You have to "increase" using the same mathematical law you used to define your first equation.

Comment: @Atmos you mean only if I multiplied the first number and divided the second number by the same amount then their product won't change ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I meant. If $ab=c$ then for $n \ne 0$
$$
\left(na\right)\left(\frac{b}{n}\right)=ab\frac{n}{n}=c
$$
With an example $8\times10=80$ and
$$
\left(2\times 8\right)\left(\frac{10}{2}\right)=16\times 5=80
$$